# Random Playing Card generator optimization

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my attempt at a Random Playing Card generator picks 1 card at random
(will be trying to make it more complicated adding in distinct card limits at a later date and maybe converting it into a snap based game).

Was wondering if anyone has any tips to optimize this query, or any bad practices I have used.

```
-- Higher or Lower
-- Deck of Cards

WITH CardNumber AS
                (
                    SELECT 1 col1, 'ACE' col2   FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2, 'Two'             FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3, 'Three'           FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4, 'Four'            FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 5, 'Five'            FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 6, 'Six'             FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 7, 'Seven'           FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 8, 'Eight'           FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 9, 'Nine'            FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 10, 'Jack'           FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 11, 'Queen'          FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 12, 'King'           FROM dual
                ) -- Assigns Card Number
                ,
CardType AS     (
                    SELECT 1 col1,'Spades' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2,'Hearts'           FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3,'Diamonds'         FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 4,'Clubs'            FROM dual  
                ) -- Assigns Card Type

-- Draw card
SELECT
            (
                            SELECT b.col2
                            FROM(
                                    SELECT CARD,tank
                                    FROM    (   SELECT CARD,
                                                RANK () OVER(ORDER BY CARD DESC) tank
                                                FROM
                                                        (
                                                            SELECT floor(dbms_random.value(1,12)) CARD
                                                            FROM dual
                                                        ) abc
                                            ) b
                                ) A
                            INNER JOIN CardNumber b
                            ON A.CARD = b.col1 AND a.tank = 1
            ) CARD_NUMBER,
            (
                            SELECT b.col2
                            FROM(
                                    SELECT CARD,tank
                                    FROM    (   SELECT CARD,
                                                RANK () OVER(ORDER BY CARD DESC) tank
                                                FROM
                                                        (
                                                            SELECT floor(dbms_random.value(1,4)) CARD
                                                            FROM dual
                                                        ) abc
                                            ) b
                                ) A
                            INNER JOIN CardType b
                            ON A.CARD = b.col1 AND a.tank = 1
            ) CARD_TYPE
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Any specific reason this needs to be done in SQL? I'm assuming its an assignment of some sorts but this really, and I can't stress this enough really should be done on the server 99% of the time as maintaining and versioning SQL scripts is a nightmare for production ready code.

Comment: found out about "dbms_random.value()" and wanted an excuse to use it, was the only scenario I could think of that wasn't "SELECT dbms_random.value() FROM dual;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks way more complicated than I would expect. I would expect a CTE called `deck`, which would have 52 cards in the deck. Then you would pull the cards from the "deck".

This would be something like

```
with CardNumber as ( . . . ),
     CardSuit as ( . . . ),
     Deck as (
      select cs.col2 as suite, cn.col2 as number
      from CardNumber cn cross join
           CardSuit cs
    )
select *
from deck
order by dbms_random.value()
fetch first 1 row only;
```